# Using a Raspberry PI as router and FTP server

Tags: networking, router, ftp, raspberry-pi

I am foreign at building networks thus, I would like to seek some advice. Essentially, I would like to use my raspberry pi both as a wireless router and ftp server, in my campus room (with a single ethernet port). I would like to keep my laptop wired to the room, thus I am thinking of designing a network that looks something like this:

[image]

Would this work? I'd appreciate any advice and recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

install hostapd and vsftp or similar.
Configure them and you are done.

Here are some basic instruction to help with [hostapd](https://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/)
https://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/

Here some ftp server install docs direct from raspberry pi.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ftp.md

You should still setup security to prevent your Pi being hacked.